# CKEditor not populating data received the API

Tags: reactjs, axios, ckeditor

Currently I am using formik to show the data received from the API and it works with the help of
`enableReinitialize={true}` but I am now using CKEditor with it too and I am expecting the CKEditor to show the data received from the API, Following is my code :

```js
<Formik
                enableReinitialize={true}
                initialValues={id ? updatedSchema : initialValues}
                validationSchema={AddNewSchema}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                  dispatch(actions.createFAQ(values));
                }}
              >
                {({ handleSubmit, setFieldValue }) => (
                  <>
                    <Form className="form form-label-right">
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <Field name="question" component={Input} label="Question *" withFeedbackLabel={false} />
                        <ErrorMessage name="question" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Answer *</label>
                        <CKEditor
                          name="answer"
                          editor={ClassicEditor}
                          onInit={(editor) => {
                            // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                            console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
                          }}
                          onChange={(event, editor) => {
                            const data = editor.getData();
                            setFieldValue("answer", data);
                          }}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <ErrorMessage name="answer" component="div" className="invalid-feedback" />

                      <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-6 form-group">
                          <Select name="status" label="Status *" withFeedbackLabel={false}>
                            {status.map((option, key) => (
                              <option key={key} value={option.value}>
                                {option.label}
                              </option>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                        Save
                      </button>
                    </Form>
                  </>
                )}
              </Formik>
```

Expected : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY8ky.png
Actual https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjYhm.png

Comment: Could you give an example on the expected outcome and whats the actual outcome?

Comment: @MaddEye Yes added

Comment: I have fixed the issue with the help of data attribute in CKEditor, will post full answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react CKEditor, it has a `data` property which allows to show initial data, I just used it to show data received from the server / API

```
 <CKEditor name="answer" editor={ClassicEditor} data={updatedSchema.answer} 
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                 setFieldValue("answer", data);
                }}
/>
```